# jQuery :contains() selector fails on specific string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this expression to find a div which contains a botanical name. Because of the nature of botanical names, they sometimes need to contain some special characters.

It works for every botName I've tried except for this one: "Cornus florida var rubra", and I cannot figure out why. In fact, it even works for "Cornus florida var".

I do not have control over the selection or format of botanical names, so changing the original name is not an option.

Any ideas?

```
matchingDiv = $("[class=iconDiv]:contains(" + botName + ")");
```

html is in this format:

```
    <div id="iconDiv-Cornus florida var rubra" class="iconDiv" 
         onclick="select(this,28);" title="" 
         style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">

        <div class="table">
            <img class="imgs" src="/Library/Application Support/Xxxxx/Xxxxx/Cornus_florida_var_rubra/Cornus_florida_var_rubra.png" 
                 width="177" border="0">

            <div class="nameDiv">
                Pink-flowering dogwood<br>(Cornus florida var. rubra)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Its because you got 'Var' in there i'll bet, try `:contains('" + botName +"')");`   --note the single quote.

Comment: I agree with your hunch, but that version doesn't make a difference.

Comment: `[class=iconDiv]`  don't use attribute selectors for a class.  Use `.iconDiv` properly.

Comment: Can u update question end add where you get botName value?

Comment: Whats inside the `botName`? Where do you set that variable?

Comment: `Cornus florida var. rubra`  possible typo with the period missing in the variable?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7qd2ahk4/1/  works fine.

Comment: I don't think so--the botName is matching the div id, not the text.

Comment: Uh, contains should match against text, not children tags.  I need to reference the documentation to confirm though.  Ref. http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: what does your `select()` function look like?

Comment: [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/): _"Select all elements that **contain the specified text**"_

Comment: Right, but it does not match on parts of a child tag.  It only goes off of the **text nodes** in them.  https://jsfiddle.net/7qd2ahk4/3/  If it matched against part of tags, it would find that img tag.

Comment: I think we've figured it out. It's matching the text, not the id name.

Comment: What would be the best method to match that text within the id name, then?

Comment: <search provider of your choice>: "jquery id match partial"

Comment: I'd avoid attribute selectors against an id, but if you must, they can use `[id*="value"]` for a contains, `[id^="value"]` for starts with, and `[id$="value"]` for ends with

Comment: Actually what I would suggest is to stick that value in a data field like `data-id="your value"` and then your selector would be a more performant `$('.iconDiv').filter('[data-field="your value"]')`

Comment: FYI, spaces aren't valid in ID attribute: [The value must not contain any space characters.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#ref-for-html-element%E2%91%A0%E2%91%A2)

Comment: Thanks a ton, folks. This seems to work: $('.iconDiv').filter('[id*="'+ botName + '"]')

Answer (score 0):

:contains() was finding matching child **text**, not the matching child id, and this made the crucial difference in a few cases. Thanks, Taplar and Andreas!

This ended up working:

```
$('.iconDiv').filter('[id*="'+ botName + '"]')
```

Comment: Incidentally, I would have preferred to use a data attribute as well (like Taplar suggested), but div id was requested in this case.

Comment: Why the downvotes? The error was not a typo. I needed to find child id, not child text, and was misusing :contains. Thanks to helpful answers, I learned something. Would love to know how to do this better next time.